# CSS menu hide current submenu when other menu item is hovered

Tags: css, joomla, menu

I'm designing a new website, but I currently have the following problem:

In the menu, when the I open a page with a sub menu, and then hover a menu item without sub menu I want to display an empty gray bar. But I've got no clue how to do this.
To reproduce this go to this page: http://www.kvvikingvenlo.nl/joomla/nl/aluminium-gietwerk.html and then hover over the home item in the menu. (Home has no sub menu, so I want the gray bar to be empty.)

**Edit**

I'm sorry, my question seems to be quite hard to understand. Lets try again:

On the web page http://www.kvvikingvenlo.nl/joomla/nl/aluminium-gietwerk.html there is a menu which is always displays the current sub menu, until you hover a different sub menu. This part is already working.

But when you hover Home, you will still see:"ONTWIKKELING, HOGEDRUK SPUITGIETEN, CNC-NABEWERKING and MONTAGE".

These are the sub menu items of the parent "Processen" (which is the current active one)

Because home does not have any sub menu items, i want this bar to be empty instead.

Comment: How about just placing an empty UL and LI after the home link?

Comment: I don't get the question... the page you you linked has the effect you want to reproduce?

Comment: @BillyMoat I'm not sure, the menu is generated by joomla, I will have a look if i can edit the menu module to do this.

Comment: @Joum if you go to the page i provided, and hover over the Home menu item, there wont be an empty gray bar, but it will display the sub menu of the active parent.

Comment: So you always want to show the current section's submenu, even if you are hovering a different section?

Comment: @Joum I edited the first post, hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up in making a template override in joomla so that it inserted an empty ul tag in the menu. I thought this would be the cleanest option I had.

To make a template override copy the file \modules\mod_mainmenu\tmpl\default.php to \templates\YOURTEMPLATE\html\mod_mainmenu\default.php

Then find this code in the file you copied:

```
if (isset($path) && $node->attributes('id') == $path[0]) {
    $node->addAttribute('id', 'current');
} else {
    $node->removeAttribute('id');
}
$node->removeAttribute('rel');
$node->removeAttribute('level');
$node->removeAttribute('access');
```

And add these lines just BEFORE them.

```
if (($node->name() == 'li') && !isset($node->ul)) {
    $node->addChild('ul ');
    $node->addChild('/ul');
}
```

Hope I helped anyone!

Answer (score 0):

i think you would have to do this through javascript, you have you `.active` on your `ul` and that is the parent you your `li` what is the parent to your `a` so in order to change the child tag to display as `.active` you would do this through javascript. i hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, if there is no submenu to the menu section, you just want to display the grey bar beneath.

This menu is being done with nested UL and LI tags with CSS, it is a very common technique.
I should warn you though, that the effect in the page you linked doesn't do what you need in IE <9. There are a few pure CSS menu examples that achieve this purpose quite easily.

If you don't want (or know) how to change it because it would mean messing with Joomla's inner workings, what I think you can do is: first create an empty SPAN inside a "fake" LI under HOME, then, set that specific (via `class` or `id` attribute in the HTML) SPAN with width equal to the gray bar. then set `display:block;` to the SPAN. This has to be done when the `:hover` event occurs in the parent class of the SPAN.

For example:
If you set the `class` of the SPAN tag to *hideme*:

`.menumenu li ul li .hideme {
    width: [width of the grey bar];
}`

.menumenu li:hover ul li .hideme { display:block; }

It's not pretty, but it should work.

**EDIT** I had the right idea, but wrong execution (too early in the morning)

What you actually need is to give a unique identifier to a fake UL under the HOME LI (ie *fakeUL*), nest a LI inside of it to hold a SPAN tag, define the size of that SPAN tag with the `width` property, and then the CSS could be something like:

`.menumenu li .fakeUL li span {
    width: [width of the grey bar];
}`

.menumenu li:hover .fakeUL li span { display:block; }

Comment: This is indeed what i wanted. 

First, i just tried the website in IE6, IE7, IE8 and IE9. 

In IE6 The website is not working at all, but i already included a bar telling users they should upgrade. 

In IE7 the menu works, but the only problem is that the submenu is not alligning totally right: http://www.kvvikingvenlo.nl/joomla/knipsel.png

In IE8 and higher its all working.

Comment: About your solution, It brought me an other idea which might work as well.
I allready have a div which is behind the submenu (.menubargrey), if i could change the z-index of that one so it comes in front of the submenu then the submenu will be hidden behind it. I only don't know how to change the styling when hovering a different div.

Comment: I don't really recommend you using Z-index for this effect. Remember that this UL>LI has same-level submenus that you need to show, so it may be difficult/hard work to code conditionally to this one and forget about the others. Did this approach work?

Comment: I just now noted that this solution actually might require you to set a unique identifier to the _HOME_ LI too, otherwise this will show the grey span everytime one of the first level LIs is hovered.